# How to change DataSource binding from DataGridView

Tags: vb.net, optimization, datagridview, dataset

I have a problem changing the DataSource of my DataGridView.
I had a Problem, that really slowed down my code. By setting the DataSource the first time it "only" took 4sec. Changing the DataSource took 23sec. And this is not acceptable(the bigger the database the longer it takes)

I changed a bit here and there - now my worst problem still takes 0.06sec while setting and 3.66sec while changing the DataSource.

How do I fix this? It seems to delete or write every single row while changing the DataSource instead of replacing it...

Thanks in advance :)

```
Private Sub getData(ByVal selectCommand As String)

    Try

        Dim connectionString As String = _
                            "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" &
                            "Data Source=" & dbPath & ";"
        Dim ds As DataSet
        Dim dt As DataTable
        Dim da As OleDbDataAdapter
        Dim cb As OleDbCommandBuilder

        ds = New DataSet()
        da = New OleDbDataAdapter(selectCommand, connectionString)
        cb = New OleDbCommandBuilder(da)

        da.Fill(ds, "Main")
        dt = ds.Tables("Main")

        Dim z As Integer = 0
        For Each item As String In lstColumnNames
            dt.Columns(z).ColumnName = item
            z += 1
        Next

        If bs.DataSource IsNot Nothing Then bs.DataSource = Nothing

       ' v v v v v * Problem seems to be here * v v v v v
        bs.DataSource = dt
       ' ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ 

    Catch ex As OleDbException
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: How many rows does this return? If it's too much could you filter it down to a smaller chunk. I mean no one like to scroll thru 1000's of lines of data right?

Comment: You need to "run" the grid in virtual mode. Here's a walkthrough: **[Implementing Virtual Mode in the Windows Forms DataGridView Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/15a31akc(v=vs.90).aspx)**